# useEffect() not work with a large Component

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I have a problem when try to render a large Component, about more than 300 code lines, and the use Effect() function does not work. I use use Effect() to load data, and storage to state. When I remove all the components that use the state , it works again, after that, I add one by one child component, it still works until about 4 components and take error again. damn, I spend 8 hours to fix and fail. there is my code, I rewrote and you can copy paste it to test. Thanks for your help.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
View,
Text,
TouchableOpacity,
ScrollView,
Image,
StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

const HomeDetail = () => {

const icon = { uri: 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconfinder.com%2Ficons%2F211614%2Farrow_b_down_icon&psig=AOvVaw1MEXG4kbEmt_x8DBErEnbI&ust=1617875579779000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMCKyqvu6-8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD' }

const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [showDescription, setShowDescription] = useState(false)
const [showNearbySchools, setShowNearbySchools] = useState(false)
const [titleNameInput, setTitleNameInput] = useState(false)
const [titleEmailInput, setTitleEmailInput] = useState(false)
const [titlePhoneInput, setTitlePhoneInput] = useState(false)
const [showFooterTab, setShowFooterTab] = useState(false)
const [timeOnRealtor, setTimeOnRealtor] = useState()

useEffect(() => {

    const getData = () => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://realtor.p.rapidapi.com/properties/v2/detail',
            params: { property_id: 'R4061264803' },
            headers: {
                'x-rapidapi-key': '7abe4815e1msh8ad18eb0e589c4cp1fc2e5jsn96386487842d',
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'realtor.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        };

        axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
            setData(response.data.properties[0])
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    getData();
}, [])

const TextLink = (prop) => {
    styles = prop.style ? prop.style : {}
    textDecorationLine = prop.underLine ? 'underline' : 'none'
    return (
        <Text
            style={[styles,
                {
                    color: prop.color,
                    fontSize: prop.fontSize,
                    textDecorationLine: textDecorationLine
                }
            ]}
            onPress={prop.onPress}
        >
            {prop.text}
        </Text>
    )
}

const ButtonCustom = (prop) => {
    colorText = prop.type ? prop.color : 'red';
    colorBackground = prop.type ? 'white' : prop.color;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[prop.style,
            {
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                height: 35,
                paddingLeft: 10,
                paddingRight: 10,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 30,
                borderColor: prop.color,
                backgroundColor: colorBackground,
            }
            ]}
            onPress={prop.onPress}
        >
            <Text style={{
                color: colorText,
                fontSize: prop.fontSize,
                // fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
            >
                {prop.text}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
return (
    <ScrollView>
        <View>
            <TextLink text='aaaaaa' color='blue'></TextLink>
        </View>

        {/* <View style={{ paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22 }}>${data.price ? data.price : 5}/mo</Text>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <Image style={[style.image, { marginLeft: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                    <Image style={[style.image, { marginLeft: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                    <Image style={[style.image, { marginLeft: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <Text>{data?.address?.line ? data.address?.line : '---'}, {data?.address.city ? data?.address.city : '--'}, {data?.address.state_code ? data.address.state_code : '--'} {data?.address.postal_code ? data.address.postal_code : '--'}</Text>
        </View> */}
        {/*<View style={{ paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
            <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                width: '100%',
                borderBottomColor: 'gray',
                borderBottomWidth: 1
            }}>
                <View style={{ paddingRight: 5, borderRightWidth: 1, borderRightColor: 'gray', marginRight: 5 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{data?.beds}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'gray' }}>beds</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ paddingRight: 5, borderRightWidth: 1, borderRightColor: 'gray', marginRight: 5 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} >{data?.baths}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'gray' }}>baths</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ paddingRight: 5, borderRightWidth: 1, borderRightColor: 'gray', marginRight: 5 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{data?.sqft ? data?.sqft : '--'}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'gray' }}>sqrt</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ paddingRight: 5, marginRight: 5 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                        {data?.client_display_flags.allows_cats | data?.client_display_flags.allows_dogs | data?.client_display_flags.allows_dogs_small | data?.client_display_flags.allows_dogs_large ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'gray' }}>pet</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <TextLink text='How much home can you afford ?' color='blue' />

            <View style={{}}>
                {data?.listing_status ?
                    (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                        <Image style={[style.image, { marginRight: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                        <Text>{data?.listing_status}</Text>
                    </View>) : null
                }
                {data?.prop_type | data?.prop_status ?
                    (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                        <Image style={[style.image, { marginRight: 5 }]} source={.icon} />
                        <Text>{data?.prop_type, data?.prop_status}</Text>
                    </View>) : null
                }
                {timeOnRealtor ?
                    (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                        <Image style={[style.image, { marginRight: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                        <Text>{timeOnRealtor} ons realtor.com®</Text>
                    </View>) : null
                }
                {data?.year_built ?
                    (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                        <Image style={[style.image, { marginRight: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                        <Text>Built in {data?.year_built}</Text>
                    </View>) : null
                }
                {1 ?
                    (<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                        <Image style={[style.image, { marginRight: 5 }]} source={icon} />
                        <Text>style
                            <TextLink text='ASK AGENT' color='blue' />
                        </Text>
                    </View>) : null
                }

            </View>
            <TextLink text='MORE DETAILS' color='blue' />
            <ButtonCustom text='EMAIL AGENT' color='red' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ padding: 10, borderColor: 'gray', borderTopWidth: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
            <TextLink text='SEE MORE ABOUT THIS BUILDING' color='blue' />
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ padding: 10 }}
            onPress={() => setShowDescription(!showDescription)}
        >
            <Text>Description</Text>
            {showDescription ?
                (<Text numberOfLines={1} >{data?.description}</Text>) :
                (<View>
                    <Text >{data?.description}</Text>
                    <TextLink text='MORE' color='blue' />
                </View>)
            }

            <Image style={{
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 0,
                top: showDescription ? 20 : 30,

            }}
                source={showDescription ? icon : icon}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
                padding: 10,
                borderBottomColor: 'gray',
                borderTopColor: 'gray',
                borderWidth: 1,
            }}
            onPress={() => setShowNearbySchools(!showNearbySchools)}
        >
            <Text>Nearby Schools</Text>
            {showNearbySchools ?
                (<Text > Ratings: Elementary {data?.ratings.great_schools_rating} High {data?.ratings.parent_rating}</Text>) :
                (<View>
                    {data?.schools.map((item, index) => {
                        if (index < 3) {
                            return (
                                <View
                                    key={index}
                                    style={{
                                        flexDirection: 'row',
                                        justifyContent: 'space-between',
                                        paddingTop: 10,
                                        paddingBottom: 10,
                                        borderBottomWidth: index == 3 ? 1 : 0,
                                        borderBottomColor: 'gray'
                                    }}>
                                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                        <View style={{
                                            height: 40,
                                            width: 40,
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            borderWidth: 3,
                                            borderColor: item.ratings.great_schools_rating ? 'green' : 'gray',
                                            borderRadius: 40,
                                        }}>
                                            {item.ratings.great_schools_rating ?
                                                (<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.ratings.great_schools_rating}
                                                    <Text>/10</Text>
                                                </Text>) : (<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Not Rated</Text>)
                                            }

                                        </View>
                                        <View>
                                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                                            <Text>{item.funding_type}   Grades
                                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.grades.range.low} - {item.grades.range.high}</Text>
                                            </Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.distance_in_miles}</Text>
                                        <Text>mi.</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                        ;
                    })}
                </View>)
            }

            <Image style={{
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 0,
                top: showNearbySchools ? 20 : 30,

            }}
                source={showNearbySchools ? icon : icon}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10,
                borderBottomColor: 'gray',
                borderBottomWidth: 1
            }}>
                Additional Info
            </Text>
            <View style={{
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10,
                borderBottomColor: 'gray',
                borderBottomWidth: 1
            }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Presented By</Text>
                <TextLink text={data?.agents.name} color='blue' />
            </View>
            <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: 'gray'
            }}>
                <Image
                    style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
                    source={{ uri: data?.office.photo.href }} />
                <View style={{
                    paddingTop: 10,
                    paddingBottom: 10,
                    borderBottomColor: 'gray',
                    borderBottomWidth: 1
                }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Brokered By</Text>
                    <TextLink text={data?.office.name} color='blue' />
                    <TextLink text={data?.office.advantage_phone.display_number} color='blue' />
                </View>
                <View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Text>Source        {data?.mls.name}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>property ID       {data?.mls.id}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', padding: 10 }}>
                <Image style={{ height: 10, width: 10 }} source={icon} />
                <Text>Be aware of scrams. Situations like wire transfers are red flags.
                    <TextLink text=' Read More' color='blue' />
                </Text>
            </View>

        </View>
        {
            data.photo ?
                (<Image style={{ width: '100%', height: 100 }} source={data.photo[0].href} />)
                : null
        }
        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 10 }}>More about this property</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10 }}>
                <Image source={icon} />
                <TextLink text={data.building_href} color='blue' />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginRight: 10 }}>Move in</Text>
                <Text>2021-04-20</Text>
                <Image style={{ height: 10, width: 10, marginLeft: 10 }} source={icon} />
            </View>
            <View>
                {titleNameInput ?
                    (<Text style={{ fontSize: 12, position: 'absolute', top: -2 }}>Name</Text>)
                    : null
                }
                <TextInput style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                }}
                    placeholder='Name'
                    onPressIn={() => setTitleNameInput(true)}
                    onPressOut={() => setTitleNameInput(false)}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                {titleEmailInput ?
                    (<Text style={{ fontSize: 12, position: 'absolute', top: -2 }}>Email</Text>)
                    : null
                }
                <TextInput style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                }}
                    placeholder='Email'
                    onPressIn={() => setTitleEmailInput(true)}
                    onPressOut={() => setTitleEmailInput(false)}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                {titlePhoneInput ?
                    (<Text style={{ fontSize: 12, position: 'absolute', top: -2 }}>Phone</Text>)
                    : null
                }
                <TextInput style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                }}
                    placeholder='Phone'
                    onPressIn={() => setTitlePhoneInput(true)}
                    onPressOut={() => setTitlePhoneInput(false)}
                />
            </View>
            <TextInput style={{
                width: '100%',
                borderRadius: 3,
                borderColor: 'gray',
                borderWidth: 1,
                paddingLeft: 5,
            }}

                defaultValue='I am interesting in ...'
            />
            <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                padding: 10
            }}>
                <ButtonCustom text='EMAIL AGENT' type={false} />
                <Text>  or  </Text>
                <ButtonCustom Text='CALL AGENT' type={false} />
            </View>
            <Text>by proceeding ...
                <TextLink text='More...' color='blue' />
            </Text>
        </View>
        {showFooterTab ?
            (<View style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                padding: 5,

            }}>
                <ButtonCustom text='EMAIL AGENT' color='red' type={false} />
                <View>
                    <TextLink text='<' />
                    <Text>1/200</Text>
                    <TextLink text='>' />
                </View>
            </View>)
            : null
        } */}
    </ScrollView>
)
}
export default HomeDetail

const style = StyleSheet.create({
image: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    resizeMode: 'cover',

}
})
```

Comment: Your problem isn't so much with the useEffect hooks but the way you access data etc. When running this code, it fails with errors such as `undefined is not an object` when accessing properties within the data object, and has many syntax errors. Consider installing eslint if you haven't and using it to lint your code and point those errors out.

Comment: thank, I misunderstood that the useEffect() is run before render function. I do not create a default state  so when rendering it can not access properties of the data object. I misunderstood the useEffect() run fist and put data to state. :)

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry everyone because of this fundamental error, I misunderstood that the useEffect() is run before render function. I did not create a default state, so when it render, it can take a default value and make an error, and the effect function can run to put data to state :) Thank for reading my problem